# SQL server -- Table not allowing insert or update of records

Tags: sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL database that we have been using for several years.  Starting this morning a single table in the database is throwing a time-out error whenever we attempt to insert or update any records.

I have tried to insert and update through:

- Microsoft Access ODBC
- a .Net Program via Entity Framework
- a stored procedure run as an automatic job -- that runs each morning
- a custom query written this morning to test the database and executed through SQL Server Management Studio
- Opening the table directly via 'Edit Top 200 Rows' and typing in the appropriate values

We have restarted the service, then restarted the entire server and continue to get the same problems.  The remainder of the database appears to be working fine.  All data can be read even from the affected table, and other tables allow updates and inserts to be run just fine.

Looking through the data in the table, I have not found anything that appears out of the ordinary.

I am at a loss as to the next steps on finding the cause or solution.

Comment: Did all of the above fail? If so, sounds like something has a lock on the table and isn't releasing it.

Comment: I would suggest running something like sp_whoisactive http://whoisactive.com/ to see if there is blocking going on.

Comment: yes all failed.  I have run sp_lock and sp_who2 and cannot find a lock in either place.

Comment: Are there are any triggers on that table?

Comment: I reset the server again over lunch time and the issue seems to have resolved.  I was not able to determine the cause, but I appreciate the comments.  I will update again if the issue comes back.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a space issue is it ? try ...

```
    SELECT volume_mount_point Drive, 
    cast(sum(available_bytes)*100 / sum(total_bytes) as int) as [Free%],
    avg(available_bytes/1024/1024/1024) FreeGB
from sys.master_files f
cross apply sys.dm_os_volume_stats(f.database_id, f.[file_id])
group by volume_mount_point
order by volume_mount_point;
```